# Problems assigning value with setState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, react-hooks, use-state

New to using React and having some trouble trying to get changes to a Textfield to update state. Using a functional component where the initial state is set with useState.

I'm sure I'm just missing something simple... but finally giving up and asking for help.

Here's the full code for the functional component:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import Step1 from '../Element/FormStep1';

const NewForm = () => {

  let [object, setObject] = useState({
    property: {
      entry: 'string'
    }
  });

  function handleChange(event) {
    const {name, value} = event.target;
    setObject({
      ...object,
      [name]: value
    })
    console.log(object)
  };

  return (      
    <form>     
        <Step1 
          handleChange={handleChange}
          object={object}
        />                        
    </form>
  );
}

export default NewForm
```

And for the Form Component:

```
import React from 'react';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import t from 'typy'

export default function Step1(props) {

  return(
    <React.Fragment>
      <TextField
        name={t(props.object, 'property.entry').safeObject}
        type='text'
        onChange={props.handleChange}
      />
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```

When the handleChange function runs, instead of replacing the target property, it creates a new property with the original value as the name i.e.

```
object {
  property: {
    entry: 'string'
  },
  string: value //Text input
}
```

The intention is to replace the value ‘string’ with the text input.

```
 object {
   property: {
     entry: 'value' //Text input 
   }
 }
```

Comment: Where does `...object` comes from?

Comment: What does `setObject` do?

Comment: please provide a full code. Can't be answered otherwise.

Comment: @errorQD please add useState line

Comment: From your question, I can't understand what is wrong and how it should be, could you add the desired behavior and how it's wrong. (Show how the object should be if it worked correctly)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I managed to figure this out after some sleep, and more online research. Using the set method from lodash was the way to go. So a minor change to the name property on my Textfield was required:

```
<TextField
  name='property.value'
  type='text'
  onChange={props.handleChange}
/>
```

And after importing set in my function component file, `import { set } from 'lodash';` I could amend the handleChange function as follows:

```
function handleChange(event) {
  const {name, value} = event.target;
  set(object, name, value)
  console.log(object) // to see that it worked in the console. 
}
```

This is now working as intended (several hours of frustration later)

Note... here's where I actually found the answer:

https://levelup.gitconnected.com/handling-complex-form-state-using-react-hooks-76ee7bc937

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have an object with a value property, you should add `{}`.

You should change

```
setObject({
  ...object,
  [name]: value
})
```

to

```
setObject({
  ...object,
  [name]: { value } // added { }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Your object will be changed in next render.

```
function handleChange(event) {
    const {name, value} = event.target;
    const newObject = {
      ...object,
      [name]: value
    } 
    setObject(newObject)
    console.log('newObject', newObject)
    console.log('currentObject', object)
  };
```

newObject != object